# Unfortunately (App name) stopes message when adding new activity to existing project

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter, android-anr-dialog

1.New Activity

```
public class RateQuizActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d("feedback", "Activity loaded");
  setContentView(R.layout.rate_this_quiz);

    Log.d("feedback", "Content View setted");
}}
```

2.call using intent--(0N button click)

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent in = new Intent(QuizByteReviewActivity.this, RateQuizActivity.class);

                     startActivity(in);


                }
            });
```

log cat displays both "Activity loaded" and 
"Content View setted" messages,but when click on button getting "Unfortunately (App name) stopes message"

Comment: also share your logcat information..

Comment: Replace your run code with this. Intent in = new Intent(RateQuizActivity.this, QuizByteReviewActivity.class);

                     startActivity(in);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Have you declared "RateQuizActivity.class" in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent in = = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                in.setClass(QuizByteReviewActivity.this, RateQuizActivity.class);

                 startActivity(in);


            }
        });
```

Add your RateQuizActivity to the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.RateQuizActivity "
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message">        
</activity>
```